# How to display ram type in output using c#?

Tags: c#, memory

I am trying to display the size and type of the ram in my project. I am using windows 7 32 bit system. I was success in printing size of ram using

```
ulong mem = ulong.Parse(CI.TotalPhysicalMemory.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Total Physical Memory:{0}",mem/(1024*1024) + " MB");
```

But cannot display type of ram using :

```
public static string GetMemoryType(int MemoryType)
 {   
   switch (MemoryType)       
   {
      case 20:
         return "DDR";
         break;

      case 21:
         return "DDR-2";
         break;    
      default:
          if (MemoryType == 0 || MemoryType > 22)
            return "DDR-3";     
          else
            return "Other";
          break;
  }
}
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Memory Type code may differ based on SMBIOS specification...that might be issue in your case

Comment: now check the answer

Answer (score 1):

.NET does not provide a way to get the type of memory I know.

The existing methodology in .Net only returns an equivalent value, but the conversion to string must be done manually following this guide: [Win32_PhysicalMemory class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394347%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

I have made a specialized class for this purpose, where I translate the codes to their respective names

```
using System;
using System.Management;

namespace Hector
{
    public class RamInfo
    {
        public static string RamType
        {
            get
            {
                int type = 0;

                ConnectionOptions connection = new ConnectionOptions();
                connection.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
                ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\root\\CIMV2", connection);
                scope.Connect();
                ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMemory");
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    type = Convert.ToInt32(queryObj["MemoryType"]);
                }

                return TypeString(type);
            }
        }

        private static string TypeString(int type)
        {
            string outValue = string.Empty;

            switch (type)
            {
                case 0x0: outValue = "Unknown"; break;
                case 0x1: outValue = "Other"; break;
                case 0x2: outValue = "DRAM"; break;
                case 0x3: outValue = "Synchronous DRAM"; break;
                case 0x4: outValue = "Cache DRAM"; break;
                case 0x5: outValue = "EDO"; break;
                case 0x6: outValue = "EDRAM"; break;
                case 0x7: outValue = "VRAM"; break;
                case 0x8: outValue = "SRAM"; break;
                case 0x9: outValue = "RAM"; break;
                case 0xa: outValue = "ROM"; break;
                case 0xb: outValue = "Flash"; break;
                case 0xc: outValue = "EEPROM"; break;
                case 0xd: outValue = "FEPROM"; break;
                case 0xe: outValue = "EPROM"; break;
                case 0xf: outValue = "CDRAM"; break;
                case 0x10: outValue = "3DRAM"; break;
                case 0x11: outValue = "SDRAM"; break;
                case 0x12: outValue = "SGRAM"; break;
                case 0x13: outValue = "RDRAM"; break;
                case 0x14: outValue = "DDR"; break;
                case 0x15: outValue = "DDR2"; break;
                case 0x16: outValue = "DDR2 FB-DIMM"; break;
                case 0x17: outValue = "Undefined 23"; break;
                case 0x18: outValue = "DDR3"; break;
                case 0x19: outValue = "FBD2"; break;
                default: outValue = "Undefined"; break;
            }

            return outValue;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = Hector.RamInfo.RamType;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## And for RAM the size

I have added a method in my class RamInfo that calculates the free, used and total space of RAM

> Note: the Hector namespace is necessary because SizeType is an ambiguous reference between System.Widows.Forms.SizeType and Hector.SizeType, so when calling SizeType you must type Hector.SizeType.YourSizeSelected

---

> First, these enumerations are used to tell the method that value should return:

```
namespace Hector
{
    public enum SizeType
    {
        Bytes = 0,
        Kilobytes = 1,
        Megabytes = 2,
        Gigabytes = 3,
        Terabytes = 4
    }
    
    public enum SpaceSelector
    {
        FreeSpace = 0,
        UsedSpace = 1,
        TotalSpace = 2
    }
}
```

> RamInfo class

```
using System;
using System.Management;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Hector
{
    public class RamInfo
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory(out long TotalMemoryInKilobytes);

        public static double RAMSize(SizeType type, SpaceSelector selector)
        {
            try
            {
                GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory(out long RamSize);
                var RAMCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes", true);

                double outValue = 0;

                double RAMTotalSizeBytes = 0, RAMFreeSizeBytes = 0, RAMUsedSizeBytes = 0,
                       RAMTotalSizeKB = 0, RAMFreeSizeKB = 0, RAMUsedSizeKB = 0,
                       RAMTotalSizeMB = 0, RAMFreeSizeMB = 0, RAMUsedSizeMB = 0,
                       RAMTotalSizeGB = 0, RAMFreeSizeGB = 0, RAMUsedSizeGB = 0,
                       RAMTotalSizeTB = 0, RAMFreeSizeTB = 0, RAMUsedSizeTB = 0;

                RAMTotalSizeBytes = RamSize * 1024;
                RAMFreeSizeBytes = RAMCounter.NextValue() * (1024 * 1024);
                RAMUsedSizeBytes = RAMTotalSizeBytes - RAMFreeSizeBytes;

                RAMTotalSizeKB = RAMTotalSizeBytes / 1024;
                RAMFreeSizeKB = RAMFreeSizeBytes / 1024;
                RAMUsedSizeKB = RAMTotalSizeKB - RAMFreeSizeKB;

                RAMTotalSizeMB = RAMTotalSizeKB / 1024;
                RAMFreeSizeMB = RAMFreeSizeKB / 1024;
                RAMUsedSizeMB = RAMTotalSizeMB - RAMFreeSizeMB;

                RAMTotalSizeGB = RAMTotalSizeMB / 1024;
                RAMFreeSizeGB = RAMFreeSizeMB / 1024;
                RAMUsedSizeGB = RAMTotalSizeGB - RAMFreeSizeGB;

                RAMTotalSizeTB = RAMTotalSizeGB / 1024;
                RAMFreeSizeTB = RAMFreeSizeGB / 1024;
                RAMUsedSizeTB = RAMTotalSizeTB - RAMFreeSizeTB;

                switch (type)
                {
                    case SizeType.Bytes:
                        switch (selector)
                        {
                            case SpaceSelector.FreeSpace: outValue = RAMFreeSizeBytes; break;
                            case SpaceSelector.TotalSpace: outValue = RAMTotalSizeBytes; break;
                            case SpaceSelector.UsedSpace: outValue = RAMUsedSizeBytes; break;
                        }
                        break;
                    case SizeType.Kilobytes:
                        switch (selector)
                        {
                            case SpaceSelector.FreeSpace: outValue = RAMFreeSizeKB; break;
                            case SpaceSelector.TotalSpace: outValue = RAMTotalSizeKB; break;
                            case SpaceSelector.UsedSpace: outValue = RAMUsedSizeKB; break;
                        }
                        break;
                    case SizeType.Megabytes:
                        switch (selector)
                        {
                            case SpaceSelector.FreeSpace: outValue = RAMFreeSizeMB; break;
                            case SpaceSelector.TotalSpace: outValue = RAMTotalSizeMB; break;
                            case SpaceSelector.UsedSpace: outValue = RAMUsedSizeMB; break;
                        }
                        break;
                    case SizeType.Gigabytes:
                        switch (selector)
                        {
                            case SpaceSelector.FreeSpace: outValue = RAMFreeSizeGB; break;
                            case SpaceSelector.TotalSpace: outValue = RAMTotalSizeGB; break;
                            case SpaceSelector.UsedSpace: outValue = RAMUsedSizeGB; break;
                        }
                        break;
                    case SizeType.Terabytes:
                        switch (selector)
                        {
                            case SpaceSelector.FreeSpace: outValue = RAMFreeSizeTB; break;
                            case SpaceSelector.TotalSpace: outValue = RAMTotalSizeTB; break;
                            case SpaceSelector.UsedSpace: outValue = RAMUsedSizeTB; break;
                        }
                        break;
                }

                return outValue;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public static string RamType
        {
            get
            {
                int type = 0;

                ConnectionOptions connection = new ConnectionOptions();
                connection.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
                ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\root\\CIMV2", connection);
                scope.Connect();
                ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMemory");
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    type = Convert.ToInt32(queryObj["MemoryType"]);
                }

                return TypeString(type);
            }
        }

        private static string TypeString(int type)
        {
            string outValue = string.Empty;

            switch (type)
            {
                case 0x0: outValue = "Unknown"; break;
                case 0x1: outValue = "Other"; break;
                case 0x2: outValue = "DRAM"; break;
                case 0x3: outValue = "Synchronous DRAM"; break;
                case 0x4: outValue = "Cache DRAM"; break;
                case 0x5: outValue = "EDO"; break;
                case 0x6: outValue = "EDRAM"; break;
                case 0x7: outValue = "VRAM"; break;
                case 0x8: outValue = "SRAM"; break;
                case 0x9: outValue = "RAM"; break;
                case 0xa: outValue = "ROM"; break;
                case 0xb: outValue = "Flash"; break;
                case 0xc: outValue = "EEPROM"; break;
                case 0xd: outValue = "FEPROM"; break;
                case 0xe: outValue = "EPROM"; break;
                case 0xf: outValue = "CDRAM"; break;
                case 0x10: outValue = "3DRAM"; break;
                case 0x11: outValue = "SDRAM"; break;
                case 0x12: outValue = "SGRAM"; break;
                case 0x13: outValue = "RDRAM"; break;
                case 0x14: outValue = "DDR"; break;
                case 0x15: outValue = "DDR2"; break;
                case 0x16: outValue = "DDR2 FB-DIMM"; break;
                case 0x17: outValue = "Undefined 23"; break;
                case 0x18: outValue = "DDR3"; break;
                case 0x19: outValue = "FBD2"; break;
                default: outValue = "Undefined"; break;
            }

            return outValue;
        }
    }
}
```

> The rest is as simple as this:

```
double FreeRamInBytes = RamInfo.RAMSize(Hector.SizeType.Bytes, Hector.SpaceSelector.FreeSpace);
double UsedRamInMegabytes = RamInfo.RAMSize(Hector.SizeType.Megabytes, Hector.SpaceSelector.UsedSpace);
double TotalRamInGigabytes = RamInfo.RAMSize(Hector.SizeType.Gigabytes, Hector.SpaceSelector.TotalSpace);
...
```

Comment: too much code for ram size lolz...It will take 5 lines at max to get the ram size

Comment: @zackraiyan Really?

Answer (score 0):

simple snippet

add namespaces manually by

Right-click   References -->.NET---> on the right and manually add System.Management --->add

```
using System.Management;
using System.Management.Instrumentation;
```

and code

```
 public string RAM_Type()
            {

                int type=0;
                var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_PhysicalMemory");
                foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
                {
                   type = Int32.Parse(obj.GetPropertyValue("MemoryType").ToString());

                }

                switch (type)
                {
                    case 20:
                        return "DDR";
                        break;
                    case 21:
                        return "DDR-2";
                        break;
                    case 17:
                        return "SDRAM";
                        break;
                    default:
                        if (type == 0 || type > 22)
                            return "DDR-3";
                        else
                            return "Unknown";
                }

            }
```

Comment: This does not make sure that correct memory type will be printed....MemoryType code may differs based on SMBIOS specificaiton

Comment: error from visual studio: ManagementObjectSearcher not found.